# Lightning Web Component - Custom Names

Tags: lightning, page-layout, lightning-web-components

I know this is not a very important question and with LWCs being new probably doesn't have an answer yet, but as I'm hoping to master these every little detail matters to me.

How do I customize the name of my component that appears on the Lighting Page Layout Editor? As you can see in the screenshot, Standard components are so nicely presented with icons, but custom components are forced to use camel casing and in addition LWCs have to have a lowercase first character. Is there not a better way?

Perhaps there is a better way to ask this question or refer to this section of the editor

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use an icon, specify a SVG file named *component*.svg in the bundle, where *component* is the name of the component (e.g. if the component name is `helloWorld`, the file is `helloWorld.svg`). You can't use standard icons by name, though you could copy the necessary code from SLDS if you'd like. To specify a label, use `masterLabel` in the *component*.js-meta.xml file. You can read more about it in [Configure a Component for Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_app_builder).